# How do I find a commercial LED with 1625nm wavelength?

Tags: led, optoelectronics

I'm looking for a LED with an emission wavelength of 1625nm for a project, but have been unsuccessful thus far in my search. How would I go about finding a commercially available LED in this range? Is there a different subset of site to look at? I can only find LEDs going up into the 1300nm range.

Comment: 1625 nm is used for fibre optic systems. Shopping questions are off-topic!

Comment: I know they're used for fibre optics systems - that's my project. I didn't know about shopping questions being off-topic, I'm sorry - if someone can close the question or do whatever needs to be done, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @LeonHeller You could be nicer about wording that. I have edited to make it about how to find the part, instead of asking for a list of parts, questions like this are on-topic. How does it look Julio?

Comment: Willing to spend $267 each? http://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=LED1600P My search terms were "long wavelength LED 1650-nm".

Comment: Alternate solution might be a shorter-wavelength LED and a phosphor.

Comment: Thanks, both for the edit and for the link, I think that will be perfect for the uses of my project.

Answer (score 1):

[GlobalSpec](http://www.globalspec.com) has almost everything. But you will have to do a free registration. Saw bunch above 1500nm...